# What type should I cast to?

Tags: java, oop

I have a form class with a method:

```
IText getSearchField()
```

The `IText` interface is something implemented by a subclass of `JTextField` called `MyTextField`.

For reasons beyond my control, I cannot get the control from the form class typed as `MyTextField`, as `JTextField`, `Component`, or anything else in the `MyTextField` type hierarchy.

I am accessing the form class object from a driver object, and would like to have the driver set the focus onto the search field retrieved by the `getSearchField()` call.

I could use the `requestFocusInWindow()` method of the `Component` class to do this.  However, first I would need to cast the result of the `getSearchField()` call to something in the `MyTextField` type hierarchy, since the call to `getSearchField()` returns an `IText`.

My question is, should I cast to `MyTextField`?  to `Component`?  to something in between?

Why?  And which would be fastest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cast to the least specific you need. That is, if A is a superclass of B and you only need methods from A, cast to A. If you also need methods from B, cast to B.

Which would be the fastest? Why do you ask this? It wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: So does that mean casting always happens at the same speed, regardless of what type you cast to?

Comment: Well, casts are surprisingly expensive because the JVM has to verify at run time that the cast is indeed legal. But I would be quite surprised if there was a significant difference in run time depending on what you cast it to. That would be amusing to benchmark. In any case, maintainability is more important than a minor performance gain even if there is one.